# Using Selenium (Java),Unable to select a particular value from dropdown

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

In my application, there is a drop down to select "Estimation Date":

[image]

Please find below my test case. It is failing at the line where I am trying to select "Since":

```
public class dropdown_issue {

    GenericFunctions gf= new GenericFunctions();

    @Test(enabled = true)

    public void dropdown () throws InterruptedException{
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:\\Selenium\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe"); 
        WebDriver dr=new FirefoxDriver();
        dr.get("http://10.127.129.79:8080/abc");

        Thread.sleep(3000);
        dr.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("user");
        dr.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("user");
        dr.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']")).click();
        WebElement est_date_dd= dr.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='clearfix']//select[@name='est-date']"));
        Select est_date= new Select(est_date_dd);
        est_date.selectByValue("Since");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        dr.quit();  
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Aalok, I observe this same behavior. "SelectByValue( )" is not working sometime. 
Work Around, When you open listbox using name I was able to click & set the actual value to list box. Let me know if it works for you too!

Comment: Thanks @NarendraC, the workaround worked. Now, trying to do it the right way. Is there any chance that I use Java script in order to accomplish this?

Comment: Great. Its fine, I have not used JS. You can use. I will add my answer below now, accept!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I observe this same behavior. `"SelectByValue( )"` doen not working sometime. Below solution worked well for me :

- **Click on listbox**
- Once list & options are visible, **Assert/Check visibility for option** which you want to select preferably by name locator
- Then using `click()` **perform click on that option** & it will set the actual value to list box.
- For confirmation, again you can **check correct value is selected** in listbox or not?

Answer (score 2):

*The value of the `option` is actually `string:SINCE`*.

Either use this value or select by visible text:

```
est_date.selectByValue("string:SINCE");

// or est_date.selectByVisibleText("Since ");
```

Comment: Hello @alecxe, I figured it out and updated the value. But that didn't work either. But, thanks for analyzing the code. 1 up for that.

Comment: @Aalok okay, thanks, what if you do `est_date.selectByVisibleText("Since ");`? (see the space after the "Since").

Comment: Okay. Will try that and share an update because I didn't put a space earlier.

Comment: Tried that but no success. Seems like Selenium does not get along well with angular. :). Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to automate AngularJS website..

From locators perspective, I don't see any problem in the code..

I would suggest to do the following -

Before selecting the drop down, try clicking on dropdown and see the code works or not.

```
    WebElement est_date_dd= 
    dr.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='clearfix']//select[@name='est-date']"));
    est_date_dd.click();    
    Select est_date= new Select(est_date_dd);
    est_date.selectByValue("Since");
```

Let me know if this doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I am getting this error when trying to select value "Since": FAILED: dropdown
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate option with value: Since

Comment: Can you please try selecting with index and see whether it works or not? Are you providing the exact text which is there in Element tree?

Comment: Yes. I am proving the same exact text but it didn't work. I tried with the index too. But doesn't seem like working. :(. Although, thank you for you efforts.